# Property [body] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel-5, slug

I get this error when I try to fetch data from my database based on slug

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function getSingle($slug) {
        // Fetch from the DB based on slug
        $post =  Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();

        // Return the view and pass in the post object
        return view('blog.single')->with('post', $post);
    }
}
```

And this is my single.blade.php

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| {{ $post->title }}')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1>hi</h1>
            <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

My database has only one row of data and it has the slug named(slug)

Comment: do {{ dd($post) }} in your view and tell us what output do you get

Comment: It shows the header properly, but for the <p> tag this is what showed up: Collection {#178 ▼
  #items: []
}

Answer (score 0):

you get data in `$post` which is an array type and what you use is object type if use a for loop in your blade then it will work fine

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| {{ $post->title }}')

@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <h1>hi</h1>
            @if($post)
                @foreach($post as $key =>$value)
                    <p>{{ $value->body }}</p>
                @endforeach
            @endif            
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Actually I tried this solution but when I refresh it only shows the header but not the paragraph.

Comment: when you refresh your page can you check what response did you get .  please dd your response